# Httpclient Xamarin Forms call not working in Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httpclient

I am having a strange problem that occurs when debugging the xamarin forms app in android physical device.

The app goes to break mode and here is the output i receive:

```
  Mono.Android[0xd6be8960] -> System[0xd6be9680]: 14
    11-24 23:44:44.098 I/Choreographer(18685): Skipped 930 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
    11-24 23:44:44.807 D/Mono    (18685): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Security[0xc17989e0] -> System[0xd6be9680]: 15
    Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
    An unhandled exception occured.
```

I tried many solutions such as allowing the network access in the app, made sure that the all needed packages are there such as:

```
Microsoft.Bcl.Build
Microsoft.net.HTTP
Newtonsoft.json
```

This is my code which works fine in UWP 
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

```
    request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;

    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    HttpContent content = response.Content;
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
    var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

EDIT: I am getting 2 main errors in the device log:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDED EXCEPTION: System.Net.HttpRequestException:An error occurred while sending the request --> System.Net.WebException:Error:SecureChannelFailure(The authentication or decryption has failed)
```

Comment: have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: it just goes to break mode without any exception or explanation

Comment: I am getting 2 main errors in the device log:
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDED EXCEPTION: System.Net.HttpRequestException:An error occurred while sending the request --> System.Net.WebException:Error:SecureChannelFailure(The authentication or decryption has failed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the default SSL/TLS implementation in Xamarin.Android.

Go to Android Project settings->Android Options->Advanced->SSL/TLS implementation and set it to **Native TLS 1.2+**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply,
i changed the above option just now and it worked

Comment: I mean the httpclient implementation, should i still change the ssl/tls?

Comment: For me just changing the SSL/TLS implementation then it works

Comment: Can you kindly update your answer to include changing the httpClient implementation too?
than, your answer will be perfect

Thanks alot for the help

Comment: @Ali123 Mine actually works if I simply switch it to Native TLS1.2 but Breaks if I also change httpclient implementation.

Answer (score 1):

On some Cases you need to chagne the **HttpClient Implementation** to be `AndroidClientHandler` instead of `Default` as the following:

[image]