# First request with HttpClient on Android takes more than 45 seconds, after that less than second

Tags: c#, android, performance, xamarin, httpclient

On Android, I have seen that Http Client takes longer for first request (around 45 to 65 seconds) and then onward, It is always less than second
Do you  know why? How can we have same response time for first request like any other requests?

Here is the sample code

```
public class HttpClientTest
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    public HttpClientTest()
    {
        HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseProxy = false,
        };
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(hch)
        {
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 100)
        };
    }

    public async Task TestHttpClientAsync(string key, string url)
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine($"TestHttpClientAsync : Start : {key} : {startTime}");
        var result = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine($"TestHttpClientAsync : End    : {key} : {endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds}");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine($"TestHttpClientAsync : Total  : {key} : {endTime} with {result?.Length}");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Here is how, I am calling it from constructor of MainPage of Shared Code

```
        HttpClientTest testHttpClient = new HttpClientTest();
        Task.Run(() => testHttpClient.TestHttpClientAsync("Google","https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")).Wait();
        Task.Run(() => testHttpClient.TestHttpClientAsync("Microsoft","https://assets.onestore.ms/cdnfiles/external/uhf/long/9a49a7e9d8e881327e81b9eb43dabc01de70a9bb/images/microsoft-gray.png")).Wait();
        Task.Run(() => testHttpClient.TestHttpClientAsync("Chrome","https://www.google.com/chrome/assets/common/images/chrome_logo_2x.png?mmfb=a5234ae3c4265f687c7fffae2760a907")).Wait();
```

Here is the result of this code
See line begining with "TestHttpClientAsync : End :" to see response time

```
TestHttpClientAsync : Start  : Google : 24/01/2018 19:39:30
TestHttpClientAsync : End    : Google : 4610.646
TestHttpClientAsync : Total  : Google : 24/01/2018 19:39:35 with 5969
TestHttpClientAsync : Start  : Microsoft : 24/01/2018 19:39:35
TestHttpClientAsync : End    : Microsoft : 681.655
TestHttpClientAsync : Total  : Microsoft : 24/01/2018 19:39:36 with 4054
TestHttpClientAsync : Start  : Chrome : 24/01/2018 19:39:36
TestHttpClientAsync : End    : Chrome : 100.584
TestHttpClientAsync : Total  : Chrome : 24/01/2018 19:39:36 with 5666
```

Comment: [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) Make your HttpClient a static shared member

Comment: @maccettura I just tried with static Httpclient instance but I got around same response time. I even tried solution posted [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480047/httpclient-xamarin-forms-call-not-working-in-android).                                                                                Here are the response times `
TestHttpClientAsync : End    : Google : 3453.561
TestHttpClientAsync : End    : Microsoft : 487.068
TestHttpClientAsync : End    : Chrome : 187.754`

Comment: @HardikPatel Can you please file a Github Issue on this? https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/new

Comment: @JonDouglas Issue raised https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1229

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is with DNS, I recommend that you try to set other DNS as 8.8.8.8 and try it again. And there are different technics for resolving DNS (to search the near server) and it can require more time, and then the next request, it knows what is the server (while resolved DNS is valid) so the request is more short . And there are more factors on connection on the internet. In my test with my 4 different servers, I do not see it, although I'm using ModernHttpClient plugin that has more features than basic. you can try it too

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/correct-way-of-using-httpclient

Comment: @cansado2930 ModernHttpClient did not work, With that, HttpClient request was timed out after 100 seconds. :(

Comment: @JonDouglas There must be really wrong. it always takes more around 64 seconds for https://storage.googleapis.com URL. It happens on more than one device over wifi and also over data network

Comment: I'm using it on production app and it works correctly. I haven't checked it if works correctly with Net 2.0, that I imagine that you are using it, no? I have created a new Project and I have added your exactly code, and results are:

Comment: google 3 seconds, Microsoft 1 seconds and the last 0.5 seconds. The Android device is a low cost, (wiko sunny) with Wi-Fi connection. Check with other DNS and/or device and tell us.